# Using a 12 bit ADC with raspberry pi

Tags: sensor

I have a LM35 sensor connected to my Pi using the MCP3204(12bit ADC). To read the values I found a python wrapper for the Spi protocol called [py-spidev](https://github.com/doceme/py-spidev).

I am following tutorials which uses use the [MCP3008](http://scruss.com/blog/2013/02/02/simple-adc-with-the-raspberry-pi/) Here is the function that reads the value from the sensor.

```
def readadc(adcnum):
```

`if adcnum > 7 or adcnum < 0:
    return -1
r = spi.xfer2([1, 8 + adcnum << 4, 0])
adcout = ((r[1] & 3) << 8) + r[2]
return adcout`

My question is Should I be changing something if I am using a 12 bit ADC?

Comment: Probably not. But just try it out, and you'll see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

The above code is only capturing a 10 bit output.

```
adcout = ((r[1] & 3) << 8) + r[2]
```

It only captures two bits from `r[1]`  (`(r[1] & 3) << 8`) plus the 8 from `r[2]`.  In reviewing the datasheet, you will need to capture the four lowest bits of r[1], so you would need to change that line to read:

```
adcout = ((r[1] & 15) << 8) + r[2]
```

15 = 0x0F or 00001111, four lowest bits.  Three of the four upper bits are unknown, which is why we are zeroing any bits which are not of interest.